# Assigning a random number to a variable in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a chat room in batch, and I want to implement colors into the program. To help distinguish different users from each other, I want to use different colored text for different users. To prevent two users' colors to conflict with each other, I want to assign a random number to a variable, and the variable can be called in the program without the previously assigned number changing. I was thinking of using `%RANDOM%`, but this doesn't seem to work. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Edit your question and post your batch chat code !

Comment: Or at least post the part relevant to the random number generation, demonstrating why `%RANDOM%` isn't working for you.  My guess is you're trying to use it in a loop and it needs its expansion delayed.

Comment: Ah, the classic "it isn't working." I've found that that often happens because.